# check the null terminating character in char*

Tags: c, string

I was just trying to see how to check for the null terminating character in the `char *` array but I failed. I can find the length using the `for` loop procedure where you keep on checking each element, but I wanted to just use the `while` loop and find the null terminating string. I never seem to exit the `while` loop. Any reason why this is so?

```
char* forward = "What is up";
int forward_length = 0;
while (*(forward++)!='/0') {
    forward_length++;
    printf("Character %d", forward_length);
}
```

Comment: did you get a warning about a multi-character constant? You're using the wrong slash its `'\0'` not `'/0'`

Comment: declare forward_length as register class might also sometimes be useful.

Answer (score 24):

You have used `'/0'` instead of `'\0'`. This is incorrect: the `'\0'` is a null character, while `'/0'` is a multicharacter literal.

Moreover, in C it is OK to skip a zero in your condition:

```
while (*(forward++)) {
    ...
}
```

is a valid way to check character, integer, pointer, etc. for being zero.

Answer (score 15):

The null character is `'\0'`, not `'/0'`.

```
while (*(forward++) != '\0')
```

Answer (score 9):

To make this complete: while others now solved your problem :) I would like to give you a piece of good advice: *don't reinvent the wheel*.

```
size_t forward_length = strlen(forward);
```

Comment: How does on use this size_t logic?

Comment: @vkaul11 What do you mean by "using this size_t logic"?

Comment: @H2CO3 Sorry,But It is always a good practice to write code for predefined functions

Answer (score 7):

Your `'/0'` should be `'\0'` .. you got the slash reversed/leaning the wrong way. Your `while` should look like:

```
while (*(forward++)!='\0')
```

though the `!= '\0'` part of your expression is optional here since the loop will continue as long as it evaluates to *non-zero* (null is considered zero and will terminate the loop).

All "special" characters (i.e., [escape sequences](http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/download/files/unprot/fortran/docs/lrm/lrm0035.htm) for non-printable characters) use a backward slash, such as tab `'\t'`, or newline `'\n'`, and the same for null `'\0'` so it's easy to remember.